# Rqt_myPlugin can't subscribe node

Tags: ros, publisher, rqt, subscribe, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I have a GUI as a rqt plugin and I want to subscribe a topic but I can't see my  rqt_plugin node on the rqt_graph.
The topic which i want to subscribe is in the same machine, which I want to start my rqt_plugin. I have muliple machines and I start the rqt_graph at the another machine. At the another machine I see all the other topics and I see also the topic which I want to subscribe with my rqt_plugin.

Here is the creation of the publisher at machine A:

```
 pubCmd = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("/sci/cmd", 10);
```

Here is the subscribing of the topic /sci/cmd at my rqt_plugin also at machine A:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = getNodeHandle().subscribe("/sci/cmd", 10, &ccgui::receiveSC, this);
```

If now I published something, my rqt plugin receives nothing. I know that the publisher works correctly because I subscribed the topic with a normal node and I receive the messages. https://github.com/Mosa-/rqt_ccgui

I hope someone can help me :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199858/rqt_myplugin-can%27t-subscribe-node/) by [Mosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/21181/mosa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-19**:
If your plugin doesn't appear in rqt_graph or in rostopic list, it's likely that the ROS node in rqt isn't getting initialized properly. That said, I don't see anything wrong with your code.

**Comment by [Mosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/21181/mosa/) on 2014-12-19**:
I follow this instruction to create the rqt plugin: http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Create%20your%20new%20rqt%20plugin in C++. How I can check in which "node universum" i am? Because I have access of the node handle... What should i do?

**Comment by [Mosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/21181/mosa/) on 2014-12-22**:
if I do rosnode list I can see the node /rqt_gui_cpp_node_7081, but where I should create the publisher/subscriber. I do it but it wont show...

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-12-22**:
May be it would help if you share your code (e.g. through GitHub) so that other people can take a look. Otherwise it might be difficult to give any specific advice.

**Comment by [Mosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/21181/mosa/) on 2014-12-22**:
Yeah he you can find the code;
https://github.com/Mosa-/rqt_ccgui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are createing a local subscriber in your function call back:

```
void ccgui::clickLabelhelpBtn_timeout(){
this->deactiveSpeechCommand("move");
ros::Subscriber sub = getNodeHandle().subscribe("/speech_control_interface/cmd", 10, &ccgui::receiveSpeechCommand, this);
ROS_INFO("topics %s %d", sub.getTopic().c_str(), sub.getNumPublishers());
// int ret = QMessageBox::information(widget_, QString("About timeout"),
// QString("Timeout between two commands.\n"
// "in [ms]"),
// QMessageBox::Close);
}
```

`sub` is destructed and deleted from stack when the at the end function's code; thereby the subscriber is also shut down and the callback will never be called!

To solve this do the following:

Declare your subscriber somewhere in the header file:

```
class ccgui
: public rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
<..............>

private:
Ui_Form ui_;
ros::Subcriber sub;
<....................>
}
```

Then subscribe as you did but without declaring the object

```
void ccgui::clickLabelhelpBtn_timeout(){
this->deactiveSpeechCommand("move");
sub = getNodeHandle().subscribe("/speech_control_interface/cmd", 10, &ccgui::receiveSpeechCommand, this);
ROS_INFO("topics %s %d", sub.getTopic().c_str(), sub.getNumPublishers());
// int ret = QMessageBox::information(widget_, QString("About timeout"),
// QString("Timeout between two commands.\n"
// "in [ms]"),
// QMessageBox::Close);
}
```

and shut it down somewhere, at the latest in plugin shutdown() (this is important because the nodehandle your retrieved by `getNodeHandle`) might live longer than your plugin so if you do not shut down the subscriber your callback might even be called after your plugin was shut down!!

```
void ccgui::shutdownPlugin()
{
   sub.shutdown();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/21181/mosa/) on 2014-12-23**:
Danke!

Thanks, this was the problem. I totally failed in a C++-trap :).